# Is the equivalent of Haskell's Foldable and Traversable simply a sequence in Clojure?

Tags: haskell, clojure, sequence, traversable, foldable

In Haskell we see [Foldable and Traversable](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldable_and_Traversable) [landing in Haskell prelude](https://twitter.com/afcowie/status/479129621162520576).

These both do operations on [sequences](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html).

```
Prelude Data.Sequence> map (\n -> replicate n 'a') [1,3,5]
["a","aaa","aaaaa"]
Prelude Data.Sequence> fmap (\n -> replicate n 'a') (1 <| 3 <| 5 <| empty)
fromList ["a","aaa","aaaaa"]
```

My question is **is the equivalent of Haskell's Foldable and Traversable simply a [sequence in Clojure](http://clojure.org/sequences)?**

**Assumptions:**

- I realise that the equivalent of [fmap in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=fmap) is [m-fmap](http://clojure.github.io/algo.monads/#clojure.algo.monads/m-fmap) in Clojure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No.** Whilst any kind of `Functor` representing finite sequences of elements will be `Traversable` (hence `Foldable`), there are plenty of other structures which are `Traversable`, but which aren't sequence-like, in that they don't have an obvious notion of concatenation. There will be a way to obtain the sequence of contained elements, but the structure may consist of more than just that sequence.

What `Traversable f` means, in effect, is that structures with type `f x` contain finitely many elements of type `x`, and that there is some way to `traverse` the structure visiting each element of `x` exactly once. So things like "terms in a syntax, seen as containing variables" can be `Traversable`.

```
data Term x
  = Var x
  | Val Integer
  | Add (Term x) (Term x)

instance Traversable Term where
  traverse f (Var x)    = pure Var <*> f x
  traverse f (Val i)    = pure (Val i)
  traverse f (Add s t)  = pure Add <*> traverse f s <*> traverse f t
```

You can always use `traverse` to do operations on all elements. We get `fmap` by taking `pure = id` and `<*>` to be ordinary application.

```
instance Functor Term where
  fmap = fmapDefault
```

where

```
fmap :: (x -> y) -> Term x -> Term y
```

implements *simultaneous renaming*.

Meanwhile, the `Foldable` instance

```
instance Foldable Term where
  foldMap = foldMapDefault
```

takes `pure` to give the neutral element of some monoid and `<*>` to the combining operation, so we get reduce-like operations. E.g.,

```
foldMap (:[]) :: Term x -> [x]
```

gives the list of variables occurring in a term. That is we can always obtain the sequence of elements from `Traversable` data, but the data might have structure other than those elements. `Term`s have structure other than variables (their `Val`s and `Add`s), and it's not so clear what "cons" means for syntax trees.

So, while more structures than sequences are `Traversable`, the `Traversable` interface offers you fewer sequence-like operations. The point of `Traversable` is to generalize *map*-like and *reduce*-like operations, not to capture *list*-ness.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out the Haskell wiki documentation on [Foldable and Traversable](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldable_and_Traversable).

First of all, **Foldable** and **Traversable** are two different type classes. As for **Foldable**, the comments made by the wiki page seem to suggest that it is pretty much the same as a Clojure sequence. Every **Foldable** has a representation as a list:

```
toList :: Foldable a => [a]
toList a = foldr (:) [] a
```

and (correct me if I'm wrong) it seems that folding over the structure is the same as folding over the associated list, i.e.:

```
foldr f b a = foldr f b (toList a)
```

In this equation the `foldr` on the left is the generic version whereas the one on the right is the one on lists.

The main difference between Haskell and Clojure here is that Clojure requires you to apply the `toList` function yourself to convert the data structure to a sequence before folding/reducing it. For flat data structures (i.e. lists, vectors, hash maps...) `toList` is just the identity function so you don't see it. On the other hand for something like trees you would need to call a function like `tree-seq` before folding it.

Comment: `foldr` is pretty much the same as folding over the list. For the `Monoid`-based `foldMap`, you *could* make up an example `Foldable` for which converting via `toList` first would give the wrong result, for example if you use `foldMap (Last . Just)` to look up the *last* element in a leftwards-infinite structure. Not sure that it comes up much in practice. :)